# How can GroupBy ILIST<>

Tags: linq, group-by, ilist

I have a the following query but showing error. how can GroupBy ?

```
IList<tbl_roadmapautomation> allproductdata = _context.tbl_roadmapautomation.GroupBy(p=>p.Stream).ToList();
```

Here "Stream" is a column name which i want to GroupBy.

ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Please suggest me how can solve this error.Advance thanks for the help.

Comment: "but showing error" isn't terribly helpful, and we've no idea what `p.Stream` is. If it's a list (as suggested by your title) how do you want to group by it? Your question is very unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var allproductdata = 
            _context.tbl_roadmapautomation.GroupBy(p=>p.Stream).ToList();
```

will work

You need convert from this result to an IList<> (eg, with a cast).

But I don't think you want to -- IList is just the interface definition, why would you want a list like that?

Answer (score 0):

Using var is nice when used inside a method, but what if you need to assign the data to a property that is needed for binding purposes. In this case,

```
public class RoadMapViewModel
{
    IList<IGrouping<int, tbl_roadmapautomation>> allproductdata {get; set;}

    // constructor
    public RoadMapViewModel(){
       allproductdata = _context.tbl_roadmapautomation.GroupBy(p=>p.Stream).ToList(); 
        }
 }
```